# How to sum values without counting through join multiple times - laravel 7

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a tricky situation in customer shop. Generally any ordered product belongs to one or more categories through product_to_categories table. Each category has translations in category_langs table. And i need to display sold products by category with total value per category. Problem is that one product could have multiple categories assigned to it and categories could have duplicated name and i need to group by name(ignoring id_category).

I've created basic sql to represent problem: https://rextester.com/KFR3316

And here is my code from laravel query:

```
$q = OrderProduct::selectRaw('category_langs.name as categoryName, sum(order_products.price_retail) AS totalProductValue')
            ->join('product_to_categories', 'product_to_categories.id_product', '=', 'order_products.id_product')
            ->join('category_langs', 'product_to_categories.id_category', '=', 'category_langs.id_category')
            ->groupBy('category_langs.name')
            ->orderBy('totalProductValue', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

**Category list is created but total value is way to big and i assume that join on products_to_categories cause counting multiple times same product.**

Many thanks for help